# How to copy a dynamic TrueCrypt volume quickly?

Tags: truecrypt

I have created a dynamic TrueCrypt volume file, set it size to 40 GiB and put about 20 GiB of files on it. When I open the volume file properties it says "Size: 40.0 GB, Size on disk: 23.0 GB". When I try to move the volume file to another physical partition it takes a lot of time as it tries to copy all the 40 GB instead of just 20 GB that the volume file actually takes. Also, when it is less than 40 GB free on the target drive it says insufficient space even though it is more than enough space considering how much does the image file actually take. How do I overcome this? Creating a new volume file on the target drive works but needless to say I'd like a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

I create a new fixed size volume on the backup drive, just large enough to fit the contents in, in your case 24Gb.

Then mount both the source and backup volumes, (say X: and Y:) and copy the files over using copy and paste. I prefer to use ROBOCOPY in a command prompt (start cmd.exe) like so:

```
robocopy x:\ y:\ /mir /r:1 /w:1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using CloneZilla in [advanced mode](http://clonezilla.org/clonezilla-live/doc/03_Disk_to_disk_clone/advanced/05-advanced-param.php) with options "-k1" (create the partition table proportionally in the target disk) and  "-r" (to resize the file file system in the partition automatically).

I cannot say this is even possible, but CloneZilla is probably one of the fastest methods of cloning disks/volumes, and maybe the most appealing option you have, even if the resizing doesn't end up working out.

Answer (score -1):

Source: http://www.truecrypt.org/docs/creating-new-volume

> Dynamic
>
> Dynamic TrueCrypt container is a pre-allocated NTFS sparse file whose
>   physical size (actual disk space used) grows as new data is added to
>   it. Note that the physical size of the container (actual disk space
>   that the container uses) will not decrease when files are deleted on
>   the TrueCrypt volume. The physical size of the container can only
>   increase up to the maximum value that is specified by the user during
>   the volume creation process. After the maximum specified size is
>   reached, the physical size of the container will remain constant.
>
> Note that sparse files can only be created in the NTFS file system. If
>   you are creating a container in the FAT file system, the option
>   Dynamic will be disabled ("greyed out").
>
> Note that the size of a dynamic (sparse-file-hosted) TrueCrypt volume
>   reported by Windows and by TrueCrypt will always be equal to its
>   maximum size (which you specify when creating the volume). To find out
>   current physical size of the container (actual disk space it uses),
>   right-click the container file (in a Windows Explorer window, not in
>   TrueCrypt), then select Properties and see the Size on disk value.
>
> WARNING: Performance of dynamic (sparse-file-hosted) TrueCrypt volumes
>   is significantly worse than performance of regular volumes. Dynamic
>   (sparse-file-hosted) TrueCrypt volumes are also less secure, because
>   it is possible to tell which volume sectors are unused. Furthermore,
>   if data is written to a dynamic volume when there is not enough free
>   space in its host file system, the encrypted file system may get
>   corrupted.

Comment: Marked down as the original poster specifically said they didn't want to have to create a new TrueCrypt volume. Although that is probably the best solution